# unix process id

Tags: unix, shell

how to a Write a script that runs a 5 instances of a child process in the background (at a gap of 5 seconds) and do a continuous check to see if any of the child process is completed it starts another instance of the same process till the child process has executed 20 instances.

Comment: this smells like homework.  also, more of a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Yep, halfway through my answer I thought the same... "What the... this is programming?!?!" may as well finish off the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but I'll do my best to guide you on the right path...

you can fork processes in your script like so:

```
/path/to/executable &
```

wait 5 seconds:

```
sleep 5
```

you can see how many instances of your program are currently running via ps:

```
ps aux | grep executable | wc -l
```

To keep track of how many instances have run, use a loop and an incrementing value:

```
#!/bin/bash
count = 0
while [ $count -lt 20 ]
do
    if [ `ps aux | grep executable | wc -l` -lt 5 ]
    then
        /path/to/executable &
        let "count += 1"
        sleep 5
    fi
done
```

the description is somewhat vague, I'm not sure if you want the 5 second gap to carry on for the subsequent 15 instances or not, and if you only want a max of 5 running at a time? That's how I interpreted it. There's many ways to implement this logic.

Comment: Should work well as long as there are no other running `executable` processes. Also, unlike my version, it has a chance of working if the target program double-forks itself away from the initial launch PID.

Answer (score 0):

This should run in most POSIX-ish shells (I tested with dash (956b4bd… from Git), ksh (“1993-12-28 p” from Mac OS X 10.4), bash (2.05b and 4.0.35), zsh (4.3.10-dev-1; actually 8a04e94… from Git)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env dash

# usage: run-em <num> <num-simul> <start-gap> <executable> [<args ...]

test -n "$ZSH_VERSION" && setopt sh_word_split

pids=''
num="$1"
num_started=0
num_simul="$2"
start_gap="$3"
shift 3

poll_gap=1 # polling interval

while test "$num_started" -lt "$num" ||
      test -n "$pids"; do
    alive_pids=''
    for pid in $pids; do
        if kill -0 "$pid" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
            alive_pids="$pid
$alive_pids"
        else
            printf 'PID %s is gone\n' "$pid" 1>&2
        fi
    done
    pids="$alive_pids"

    new_pid=''
    if test "$num_started" -lt "$num" &&
       test "$(printf "$pids" | wc -l)" -lt "$num_simul"; then
        exec 3>&1
        new_pid="$("$@" 1>&3 3>&- & echo "$!")"
        exec 3>&-
        num_started="$((num_started+1))"
        printf 'Started PID %s as #%s\n' "$new_pid" "$num_started" 1>&2
        pids="$new_pid
$pids"
        if test -n "$start_gap" &&
           test "$num" -gt 0; then
            printf 'Waiting %s seconds...' "$start_gap" 1>&2
            sleep "$start_gap"
            printf 'done\n' 1>&2
        fi
    fi
    test -z "$start_gap$new_pid" && sleep "$poll_gap"
    test "$num_started" -ge "$num_simul" && start_gap=''
done
```

Tested with: `run-em 5 2 4 sh -c 'echo "[[$$ starting]]";sleep 13;echo "[[$$ ending]]"'`

If you wanted to tie yourself to a particular shell, you might be able to use job control and a trap on SIGCHLD instead of double forking and probing with `kill -0` (ksh and zsh seem capable of this, dash and bash seem broken for this; zsh also has a jobstates parameter that could be used to check for running jobs if SIGCHLD traps happened to be broken there). In some languages (e.g. Perl), you can use `waitpid(2)` or `wait4(2)` to wait for any child process so that you could collect their actual exit codes. Unfortunately, most shells seem to only let you wait for a specific child process, which would only work if you knew ahead of time which process was going to finish first.